# How to perform the below mentioned task(vb.net)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-objects

```
Dim cells = From Qmaxminslist As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Take Integer.Parse(daysamaxminsmv.Text)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In cells
   // piece of code...
Next
```

I have converted this code in C# as:

```
dynamic cells = from Qmaxminslist in DataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() select (int.Parse(daysamaxminsmv.Text));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in cells)
{
    // piece of code...
}
```

but here comes an exception in the foreach statement saying:

> "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'"

how to solve it?
any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: in c# you have select, in vb you have take

Comment: Reread your title and ask yourself if that is helpful for any future reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't converted it correctly. The VB code selects  `DataGridViewRows`, the C# code selects `ints`. You want to take N rows. VB.NET supports `Enumerable.Take` directly in the LINQ query, C# does not support it. So i'd use method syntax in C#.

So this works as desired (don't translate `Dim` with `dynamic` but `var`):

```
int takeRows = int.Parse(daysamaxminsmv.Text);
var rows = DataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Take(takeRows);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    // piece of code...
}
```